# Console 3D Cube Rotating

Tags: c#, console, rotation, cube

What is a good algorithm for creating an "3D" cube in Console and rotating it (dice roll style)?

Creative answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an "algorithm" you'd be looking for, but you could always just do the full 3D calculations.

Example code for drawing the cube wireframe (I'm using the Vector/Matrix classes from OpenTK, you could get them from XNA or some other library as well)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using OpenTK;

class Cubes
{
    static void Main() {
        var resolution = 25;
        var points = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 8) select new Vector3(i / 4 % 2 * 2 - 1, i / 2 % 2 * 2 - 1, i % 2 * 2 - 1);
        var lines = from a in points
                    from b in points
                    where (a - b).Length == 2  // adjacent points
                       && a.X + a.Y + a.Z > b.X + b.Y + b.Z // select each pair once
                    select new { a, b };
        var t = 0f;
        while (true) {
            t += .1f;
            var projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(.8f, 1, .01f, 100f);
            var view = Matrix4.LookAt(2 * new Vector3((float)Math.Sin(t), .5f, (float)Math.Cos(t)), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitY);
            Console.Clear();
            foreach (var line in lines) {
                for (int i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
                    var point = (1f / resolution) * (i * line.a + (resolution - 1 - i) * line.b); // interpolate a point between the two corners
                    var p1 = 5 * Vector3.Transform(point, view * projection) + new Vector3(30, 20, 0);
                    Console.SetCursorPosition((int)p1.X, (int)p1.Y);
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Frames from Output:

```
                        #
                     ######
                 ####   #  ##
              ####      #   ##
           ####         #     ##
        ###             #      ##
      ##                #       ###
      ###               #         ##
      # ##              #           ##
      #   ##            #          ###
      #    ##           #       ###  #
      #      ##         #    ###     #
      #       ##        #####        #
      #         ##    ###            #
      #          #####  #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #    #            #
      #            #  #####          #
      #            ###    ##         #
      #        #####        ##       #
      #     ###    #         ##      #
      #  ###       #           ##    #
      ###          #            ##   #
      ##           #              ## #
        ##         #               ###
         ###       #                ##
           ##      #             ###
            ##     #         ####
              ##   #      ####
               ##  #   ####
                 ######
                   #
               #
              ######
            ## #    ###
           ##  #       ###
         ##    #          ####
        ##     #              ####
      ##       #                 ##
     ##        #                ###
    #          #               ## #
   ##          #             ##   #
   # ####      #            ##    #
   #     ####  #           #      #
   #        ####         ##       #
   #           #####   ##         #
   #           #    ####          #
   #           #      #           #
   #           #      #           #
   #           #      #           #
   #           #      #           #
   #           #      #           #
   #           #      #           #
   #          ####    #           #
   #         ##   #####           #
   #       ##         ####        #
   #      #           #  ####     #
   #    ##            #      #### #
   #   ##             #          ##
   # ##               #          #
   ###                #        ##
   ##                 #       ##
    ####              #     ##
        ####          #    ##
            ###       #  ##
               ###    # ##
                  ######
                      #
          #
          ##############
          #             ##########
         ##                     ##
         ##                     ##
        ###                    ###
        # #                    # #
        # #                    # #
       ## #                   ## #
       #  #                   #  #
      ##  #                   #  #
      ##############         #   #
      #   #         ##########   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   #                  #   #
      #   ##########         #   #
      #   #         ##############
      #  #                   #  ##
      #  #                   #  #
      # ##                   # ##
      # #                    # #
      # #                    # #
      ###                    ###
      ##                     ##
      ##                     ##
      ##########             #
                ##############
                             #
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good "3D cube ascii art algorithm."  I would just use a 3D cube animation - which you could create at design time or run time - and use a normal ASCII art generator.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I rotate it? I need something sample as: http://asciimator.net/?module=demo&clip_id=3827&n=4

Comment: Alon: It rotates in the animation. Rotation is a normal part of 3D animation. If you want to know how to rotate a cube in 3D, check out the javascript I wrote for the animation on my website: www.ericmickelsen.com. Or just look it up. If you want something as simple as the example you linked to in your comment, just do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a while loop which displays an array of characters generating a 3D ascii animation of the cube until you want it to stop. use something like `foreach (char spinCube in spinCubeTest)` to move the characters accordingly.